# webview color in android

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-webview, android-styles

I have this issue i have tried trough using CSS but this seems to lead me nowhere, here is what I want to do.. I have text displayed in a webview and whenever I select the text I see this: [image: first]

where the text selected is like in green color.. but I want to change that selected color to orange.. like this.. (photoshoped the image)
[image]

I have tried using CSS in my html like :

```
<style type="text/css">
::selection {
background: #E02F86;
color: white;
}
</style>
```

ans also tried with:

```
<style type="text/css">
*{
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 255);  
}
</style>
```

but non of those CSS seem to work. I'm curretly doing this for Android 3.0+ Honeycomb
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in my app. It looks like support for this selector has been dropped in CSS3:

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117/) is the working draft for CSS3 in which they state that it's no longer supported. :/

> The ::selection pseudo-element has been dropped since it was dropped from Selectors after testing found interoperability problems and further details to explore/define.